# Huge nb of parameters, constraint and objective function : how to deal with this in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, particle-swarm, cost-based-optimizer

I would like find the **Alpha** coefficients which minimize this objective function:

```
fun_Obj = @(Alpha) norm(A- sum(Alpha.*B(:,:),2),2)
```

With :

A= vector 1d (69X1)

B= matrice 2d (69X1000)

Alpha_i a vector (1X1000) of unknown parameters, where **0 < Alpha < 1** and **sum(Alpha) = 1**

What is the best optimization method to deal with such a number of parameters (I can try to reduce it will remain still a lot)?
How can I introduce the second constraint i.e **sum(Alpha_i) = 1** during the optimization?

Thanks a lot for your precious help.

Best,

Benjamin

Comment: `69*1` is considered 1D and `69*1000` is considered 2D/

Comment: Yes thanks Adriaan. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the constrained optimisation function [`fmincon`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html):

```
% sample data
nvars = 1000;
A = rand(69,1);
B = rand(69,nvars);

% Objective function
fun_Obj = @(Alpha,A,B) norm(A- sum(Alpha.*B(:,:),2),2);

% Nonlinear constraint function. The first linear equality is set to -1 to make it alway true. 
%    The second induces the constraint that sum(Alpha) == 1
confuneq = @(Alpha)deal(-1, sum(Alpha)-1);

% starting values
x0 = ones(1,nvars)/nvars;

% lower and upper bounds
lb = zeros(1,nvars);
ub = ones(1,nvars);

% Finally apply constrained minimisation
Alpha = fmincon(@(x)fun_Obj(x,A,B),x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,@(x)confuneq(x));
```

It only takes a few seconds on my laptop with the default number of iterations, but you should consider increasing that number drastically to get a better result. Also, the default algorithm might not be the right choice in this scenario, `'sqp'` is probably better. See [documentation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/choosing-the-algorithm.html).

You can do those things with:

```
options = optimoptions(@fmincon,'Algorithm','sqp','MaxFunctionEvaluations',1e6);
Alpha = fmincon(@(x)fun_Obj(x,A,B),x0,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,@(x)confuneq(x),options);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your perfect answer! It raises so many others but that one is now solved :) Cheers,